# Laravel 5 Auth - custom table with users

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel auth now and I have small problem. I read some pages from Google about this mechanism and I'm using

```
Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']]);
```

Laravel gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'base.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@domain.com limit 1)
```

In fact I don't have `users` table in my database, I'm using name `accounts`. How can I change default table in auth?

And additional question is: when I put data to Auth::attempt() data will changed to SQL query and all data will be get from base? How can I add more data than I get in base? For simple I have table `ban` which this field have number of days when ban goes end. And I want to add field `isbanned` which get TRUE/FALSE data. If `ban`>0 will be TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'isbanned' => 0]))
{
    // The user is active, not banned, and exists.
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `config/auth.php` change `'table' => 'users'` to `'table' => 'accounts'`

Comment: What can I add additional data? :)

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'isbanned' => 0]))
{
    // The user is active, not banned, and exists.
}

Comment: 'table' => 'users' is commented out for me. Should I uncomment it? If so then what effect will this have?